# How to receive dynamic data from stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core and want to receive dynamic data from my stored procedures. For example:

```
result1FromGetDataMethod = {id=xxx, datetime=xxx, isValid=xxx, ...}
result2FromGetDataMethod = {id=xxx, datetime=xxx, otherParamWhichIsNotInResult1=xxx, ...}
result3FromGetDataMethod = {completelyOtherParam=xxx, ...}
...
```

I don't know which key-value-pairs are coming from the database and I don't need to know it for my business logic. Is there a way to get dynamic data from stored procedures? I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Query<dynamic>();
    }

    public dynamic GetData(MyRequestOptions searchParams)
    {
        SqlParameter fromDate = new SqlParameter("from", searchParams.From.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        SqlParameter toDate = new SqlParameter("to", searchParams.To.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        string sqlQuery = "exec procedure @from, @to";

        var data = Query<dynamic>()
                   .FromSql(sqlQuery, fromDate, toDate);
                   .ToList();

        return data;
    }
}
```

On this example an error come with "Sequence contains no elements". If I run the procedure on the SQL Server, it runs without problems.

Comment: I found a solution on this blog: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1050214/Entity-Framework-How-to-retrieve-dynamic-data

But it's relatively slow if I have thousand of rows with more than 50 columns.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend EF Core for such a scenario. The whole point of EF is to be an ORM, which strongly relies on predefined classes, which can be mapped to sql expressions and results mapped to objects. Consider something like dapper for having more control over the execution of your queries and handling the results.

Comment: +1 for Dapper.  It supports `dynamic` out-of-the box, and you can use _both_ EF and Dapper or bare ADO.NET.

Comment: get json by `For JSON` from SQL and convert to dynamic see details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644680/2927851