# Stored procedure returns dynamic set of columns

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

SQL Server stored procedure returns a dynamic set of columns.

Up to now, I've used to declare classes which contains fixed columns names like in db and populate results through loops..

Now my stored procedure returns columns which are not fixed.

How to get it in ASP.NET Core to get desired output?

Comment: This is not a really good idea - you'll be running into headaches and troubles over and over again. I'd redesign the stored procedure to **always** return a fixed result "shape" - if you need to return multiple different result sets - have one stored procedure for each "type" of result set - it'll make your dev life much easier!

Comment: marc_s, its the requirement from user end to have data set with dymanic columns...

Comment: Dale K, I have an app that gets data from SPs, and designed classes for each data sets. I also convert them into list and send to frontend using ajax calls.

Comment: ex: public class DS1 {public string name, public string category, public string amount}

Comment: Probably I need some solution which converts DataTable/DataView into Dynamic List.. List<T> ,, or list template...

Comment: You're probably going to have to use plain ADO.NET datatables for this

Answer (score 2):

you can use `FOR JSON` in sql procedure (sql server) and retrive json string.

example:

1. sql:

   ```
   exec ('select * from @table_name for json auto')
   ```

result:

[image: sql result]

to rename the column name, wrap a statment with an alias `select (select.... for json) as 'my_json'`

.NET core

2. ```
   public class JsonFromSql{

    public string my_json {get;set;}
   ```

   }

In a Context class `OnModelCreating` method add

3. ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<JsonFromSql>(entity=> entity.HasNoKey());
   ```

call sql

4. ```
   IQueryable<JsonFromSql> result = Context.Json.FromSQLInterpolated($"myProcedureName"); 
   string data = result.Enumerable().FirstOrDefault().my_json;
   ```